# Jquery Hover - allow hover on another DIV the appears on hover of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a homepage with 4 buttons.  When hovered over a button, a menu appears behind the buttons.  When you hover over another button, a different colored menu appears in it's place.

Currently, I can get the buttons to show the menus, but when I hover onto the menus (and hover off the button) I lose the menu.

Here's my simple code:
Jquery at top:

```
$(".mybutton").hover(
    function () {
        $(".mybox").fadeIn();

    },
    function () {
        $(".mybox").fadeOut();
    }
);

$(".mybutton2").hover(
    function () {
        $(".mybox2").fadeIn();

    },
    function () {
        $(".mybox2").fadeOut();
    }
);
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="mybox">
  <div style="position: absolute;">
   <a href="#">Item 1</a>
   <a href="#">Item 2</a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<div class="mybutton">
    /* Button image here */
</div>

<div class="mybutton2">
    /* Button 2 image here */
</div>
</div>
```

So I need some way to keep the box that fades in active when it is hovered over.   I was thinking of not doing the callback for the fadeout, and somehow only doing the fadeout if they fade off the .mybox DIV or if they hover over another button.  But it's a little unclear to me how to accomplish that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/bk12f5rt/

Comment: did this fiddle work for you @916Networks?

Comment: Thanks Sushil, this code above worked perfect for what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: great. let me post this as a solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer

Comment: can you please accept my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include your menu and the button inside a container and have a hover event on the container. this way your menu will be visible as long as you're hovering over the container.

here's what you need to do.
declare the container like this with your menu and button both inside it.

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class="mybox box">
        <div style="position: absolute;">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="mybutton">
            /* Button image here */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's what you need to do in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container").hover(
        function() {
            console.log($(".mybox").fadeIn());
            $(".mybox").fadeIn();

        },
        function() {
            $(".mybox").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bk12f5rt/)** with 2 buttons

Comment: @916Networks I've posted my solution. please upvote it and mark it as an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're no longer hovering over the button and instead going to a different element "mybox" so you could rearrange the html structure for it to work by keeping the menu in the button class like so:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="mybutton">

        /* Button image here */

        <div class="mybox">
            <div style="position: absolute;">
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

this should keep the menu active as long as the curser is in there.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I implemented on my test page and it does as described, but didn't quite work as well as the jsfiddle posted by Sushil for my setup.  But this is legit code that works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this as a UI design pattern for various reasons (one of them being the complexity of implementing it); you could instead consider changing it so that the menu appears when the user clicks.

Having said that, here's a way to do it. Get rid of your existing `fadeOut()` calls and add this:

```
$("body").on("mousemove", function(e) {
     var $hovered = $(e.target);
     var $myButton = $(".myButton");
     var $box = $(".myBox");
     if ( $hovered.is( $myButton ) ) return;
     if ( $hovered.is( $box ) ) return;
     if ( $.contains( $box.get(0), $hovered ) ) return;
     $box.fadeOut();
});
```

...and similar for button2. The basic principle is this - whenever the mouse moves, we check whether the mouse is hovering over the button, or the box, or over an element contained in the box (using `$.contains()`). If not, we hide the box.

Comment: Thanks Duncan!  I tried the code above but couldn't get it to work. Assuming it was something on my side.  I appreciate the consideration of the UI, actually after thinking about it more, I might recommend click vs. hover to the client.  Thanks for taking the time.